# Ubuntu 22.04 netplan with two interfaces. Public IP not accessible on the second interface

Tags: networking, server, 22.04, netplan

I have two interfaces on an Ubuntu 22.04 server hosted in AWS. Both have public IP addresses, however; only ens5 is responding to incoming traffic. When I run a tcpdump on ens5 I can see my ping request hit the interface, but replies are not being sent. I actually need to add two more interfaces in the same subnet with public IP addresses, but I am struggling with netplan. Any advice would be appreciated.

**config**

```
 network:
        ethernets:
            ens5:
                dhcp4: false
                dhcp6: false
                addresses:
                   - 10.50.0.34/24
                routes:
                    - to: default
                      via: 10.50.0.1
                nameservers:
                  addresses: [8.8.8.8]
            ens6:
                dhcp4: false
                dhcp6: false
                addresses:
                   - 10.50.0.225/24
        version: 2
```

**ip route details**

```
default via 10.50.0.1 dev ens5 proto static
10.50.0.0/24 dev ens6 proto kernel scope link src 10.50.0.225
10.50.0.0/24 dev ens5 proto kernel scope link src 10.50.0.34
```

**ip a details**

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: ens5: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 02:91:f4:8f:d1:76 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    altname enp0s5
    inet 10.50.0.34/24 brd 10.50.0.255 scope global ens5
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::91:f4ff:fe8f:d176/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: ens6: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 02:87:1d:02:5c:c6 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    altname enp0s6
    inet 10.50.0.225/24 brd 10.50.0.255 scope global ens6
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::87:1dff:fe02:5cc6/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Comment: If the network routes traffic for 10.50.0.225 to your ens5 interface, why do you have that IP address configured on ens6 instead of on ens5?

Comment: Do you have forwarding turned on in the kernel? It is not on by default, and if it's not on, traffic received on ens5 for an address on ens6 will not be forwarded across to ens6.

Comment: @slangasek - Good point. I did not realize I could add additional public IPs to a single interface in AWS. Once I added the new private and public IPs to the interface and changed my netplan to account for the new addresses, everything worked like a charm. Thank you! I was over complicating my use case.